# The usage of pronoun "it"

Tags: pronouns

Is it correct if I use **it** in this sentence?

> If we pull one's hair, **it** could hurt the scalp.

I'm using **it** because I'm referring to the action of *pulling hair*. So the action could hurt the scalp but I feel like the sentence sounds weird with the usage of **it** in there.

Comment: Why do you think "it" looks weird there? Is it because you think that "it" may be thought to relate to "hair", and not to the action of pulling one's hair?

Comment: Do you mean: if a person pulls out some of their hair? Or: if a person pulls out one hair from their scalp? Yes, it does hurt, either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence is correct. "It" can refer to either an object or an action.

> I hate my hair. It's so hard to manage.

"It" refers to an object, "hair".

> Don't hate your hair. It's an extreme response.

"It" refers to an action, "hate".

Comment: If some of your hair gets pulled out, it can hurt. it refers to the action of pulling out the hair. Not just "the hair".

Comment: @Lambie Yes, exactly.